# Insert data from dataframe to clickhouse table ERROR

Tags: python, dataframe, clickhouse

I'm trying to insert data from dataframe to my clickhouse table. Types are matching, I don't have any FLOAT fields, still get an error: 'TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()'

Table table_main:

```
client.command('''CREATE TABLE db1.table_main ( 
                scroll_id String,
                took Int64,
                timed_out Boolean,
                shards_total Int64,
                shards_successful Int64,
                shards_skipped Int64,
                shards_failed Int64,
                hits_total_value Int64,
                hits_total_relation String,
                hits_max_score String,
                key Int64,
                terminated_early String) 
                ENGINE MergeTree
                ORDER BY key''')
```

Dataframe table_main:

```
scroll_id              object
took                    int64
timed_out                bool
shards_total            int64
shards_successful       int64
shards_skipped          int64
shards_failed           int64
hits_total_value        int64
hits_total_relation    object
hits_max_score         object
key                     int64
terminated_early       object
dtype: object
```

Command:

```
client.insert_df('db1.table_main', table_main)
```

Could you please give any guess what's wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

This might occurs when there's a mismatch between the expected data types in ClickHouse and the actual types in the DataFrame you're trying to insert. Even though the types might seem to match, there could be some data inconsistencies causing this issue.

You can try explicitly specifying column types during insertion to ensure they match your expectations.

```
client.insert_df('db1.table_main', table_main, column_types={'scroll_id': 'String', 'took': 'Int64', 'timed_out': 'Boolean', 'shards_total': 'Int64', 'shards_successful': 'Int64', 'shards_skipped': 'Int64', 'shards_failed': 'Int64', 'hits_total_value': 'Int64', 'hits_total_relation': 'String', 'hits_max_score': 'String', 'key': 'Int64', 'terminated_early': 'String'})
```

Comment: thanks, error changed at least -) 

```--> 151 if ch_type.python_type == int:

          152     if 'float' in d_type:

    153         df_col = df_col.round().astype(ch_type.base_type, copy=False) 


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'python_type'```

Still no success with insertion.